Was angling tank armor a recognized doctrine during World War II?
I've been playing the game War Thunder recently. It is common knowledge in the game that angling a tank's armor, even slightly, will significantly increase the effectiveness of protection against enemy fire. This led me to wonder: was the concept of angling tank armor consciously employed or recognized as a doctrine during World War II?
I understand that sloped armor, such as that used on the German Panther or the Soviet T-34, was designed to increase the chances of deflecting incoming rounds by creating an oblique impact angle. It seems that tank designers during the war were aware of this concept, as it effectively increased the thickness of the armor relative to the incoming shot. However, I’m curious if there was formal military doctrine that instructed tank crews to actively angle their vehicles in combat to take advantage of this phenomenon, or if this was more of a result of battlefield improvisation or tactical adaptation?
Were there any notable examples where angling armor was explicitly trained for or utilized in combat?

A tank body usually resists an attack from the front. The sides are longer than the front, and have vulnerable tracks. Point the tank towards the enemy and you hide the sides. Armour on the back is just useless weight. To attack a tank, shoot at it from an unexpected direction, or wait for when it has to turn and present its side to you. If you are a tank, face the enemy. If the battlefield permits, tanks might advance as a front, but that would seem to be it. Or am I missing something?

@RichardKirk Yes, you're missing something.  If you turn the tank a bit to the side, incoming fire will come in at an angle, making the armor effectively thicker.  This can be true even if the side armor is thinner than the frontal armor.

@Ryan_L You do get a slight 1/cos increase in effective thickness if you angle your tank slightly. You can choose your angle if you know where the enemy is, and if there is only one of them. And you cannot change the angle in the vertical plane. Tanks are artillery, and the names of parts such as the glacis plate suggest the parts of a fort. I think tank drivers understood how armour worked, but I do not see that this helps them much against a hidden adversary in a real battlefield.
If your tank was asymmetric: if it had a 'shield' side and a 'weapon' side then maybe.

@RichardKirk The effect can be significant, because it's not just the effective thickness that increases, but it also impacts the terminal ballistics of the shell.  An incoming shell hitting an angled plate will deform asymmetrically and tend to be deflected away.  Adversaries may be hidden, but often you would still have a general idea where they were.  You might not know which particular bush they were behind, but you could still know they were in that general wooded area.

Yes, there was doctrine.
Reddit says

There is definitely a section in the TigerFibel that discusses angles at which the tiger can be penetrated and by what. I did Google quickly but can't find a good link. I can't remember but I think it does mention some angling of the frontal armour to maximise its effectiveness,. . .

The Tigerfibel, and the best translation I can find. Page 80 covers using angle to improve armor effectiveness.

It's page no. 80 if you count pages, it's page 84-87 if you take the numbers that are printed on the pages. Way more telling is actually the other stuff that came with the Fibel: The picture in your links subtitled "Photo showing the various supplements found in the back of the Tigerfibel.". Those big orange circles and green clover like shapes are information about enemy tanks and at which angles and ranges to hit them (because you need to get closer if the angle is not favorable, to penetrate). @nvoight

On that link the images are in German, but there is an English translation at the very bottom (outside the frame, easy to miss)

The operative words are on p. 84 of the Tigerfibel:

"Dein Panzerschutz ist somit über Eck in Wirklichkeit 18 cm dick und hält alle Kaliber bis 15.2 cm einschließlich aus."



Google translation:



"Your armor protection is therefore actually 18 cm thick across the corner and can withstand all calibers up to and including 15.2 cm."



"über Eck" is an idiomatic phrase referring to a 45 degree angle, as also shown in the dial in the right lower corner of the same page: 10:30a and 1:30p are annotated "18" and the description says these numbers are effective armor thickness in centimeters. @njuffa


Link seems to go to images from a German copy. I have no German, but a Google translation of one bit of pg 80 gave me "If you move your tank vertically, it will be 10 cm thick and can withstand all calibers up to 7.5 cm inclusive. But if you stand over the corner and move it diagonally, then it is 13 cm thick. However, a shell that hits at an angle penetrates much less than one that hits vertically." There's also a lot of illustrations of this diagonal vs. head on distance principle using the idea of slicing through a sausage.

It's page no. 80 if you count pages, it's page 84-87 if you take the numbers that are printed on the pages. Way more telling is actually the other stuff that came with the Fibel: The picture in your links subtitled "Photo showing the various supplements found in the back of the Tigerfibel.". Those big orange circles and green clover like shapes are information about enemy tanks and at which angles and ranges to hit them (because you need to get closer if the angle is not favorable, to penetrate).

The operative words are on p. 84 of the Tigerfibel: "Dein Panzerschutz ist somit über Eck in Wirklichkeit 18 cm dick und hält alle Kaliber bis 15.2 cm einschließlich aus." Google translation: "Your armor protection is therefore actually 18 cm thick across the corner and can withstand all calibers up to and including 15.2 cm." "über Eck" is an idiomatic phrase refering to a 45 degree angle, as also shown in the dial in the right lower corner of the same page: 10:30a and 1:30p are annotated "18" and the description says these numbers are effective armor thickness in centimeters.

A historian YT answered that:
He references Tiger WW-II manuals which cites angling as standard procedure -  "you should point meal times towards the enemy". I guess Germans didn't have lunch at 12:00?
And explains that modern tanks don't angle, because their side armor is much weaker than frontal armor, thus one should point the front towards the enemy.
I remember reading about a Panther WW-II manual, which also ordered NOT to angle, because the panther's side armor was weaker and angling was not worthy the hassle.

On times for lunch in Europe, the norm many places over there is breakfast around 8-9pm, lunch around 1-3pm, and dinner any time from about 6-10pm. This was the case even a century ago. The use of ‘meal times’ is still contextually strange though.

@AustinHemmelgarn I would expect a German lunch hour to be noon to 1pm (perhaps 30 minutes earlier or later than this) so a couple of hours earlier than a Spanish lunch hour in the same timezone.

The mealtimes listed on p. 85 of the Tigerfibel are 10:30a (breakfast), 1:30p (lunch), 4:30p (German "Kaffee", a bit like Swedish "fika" or British "afternoon tea"), 7:30p (dinner), and all correspond to 45 degree angling, providing an effective armor thickness of 18 cm. This is a mnemonic device, not a super accurate description of German cultural norms. In some contexts (I experienced it on construction sites in the 1980s), Germans have a second breakfast around 10am. In my experience, the time for "Kaffee" is usually more like 3pm.

Re "I remember reading about a Panther WW-II manual" The Pantherfibel directs the tank crew to avoid angling and assume a noon-ish orientation from 11:00a to 1:00p on the clock dial to get maximum protection from the front armor: "Da zeigt die schwachen Stunden nur / ein Blick zu Seitenrichtungsuhr. Von 11 bis 1, zur Mittagsstunde / da schlägt dir keiner eine Wunde."

Well, I eat breakfast at 6:00, snack at 9:00, lunch at 12:00 and afternoon break at 15:00. Luckily I'm not a tanker, b/c those angles would be bad. :D

Also The Chieftain (IIRC), when talking about German tank doctrine, also mentions that angling is a recognized tactic and even provides example from manual explaining how angling works on the example of sausage slicing (perpendicular to it's axis vs angling knife at 45 degrees), as a visual aid to imagine the armor thickness based on length of the slice.
